# Getting an "Unrecognized Symbol" error for the CTL_CODE macro

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, windows-kernel

I'm trying to define a custom CTL_CODE and masking that under another macro(as shown below). That pre-processor code is in the CPP file for my driver. It may be important to note that both, my client and driver, are under the same solution but are 2 separate projects. The driver is an empty wdm driver and the client is a windows console desktop app.

```
#define PRIORITY_BOOSTER_DEVICE 0x8000
#define IOCTL_PRIORITY_BOOSTER_SET_PRIORITY CTL_CODE(PRIORITY_BOOSTER_DEVICE, \0x800, METHOD_NEITHER, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
```

However, in my client, when I try to use 'IOCTL_PRIORITY_BOOSTER_SET_PRIORITY' for my DeviceIoControl call, I get an error "unrecognized token". I've pasted my DeviceIoControl call below. After some experimenting, Visual Studio is pointing the error at the 'CTL_CODE' macro itself. I'm very dumbfounded because this poses no issue in the driver project but does in the client project. Furthermore, I don't know why the issues lies with the CTL_CODE macro itself. I'd assume that the macro is defined in the WDK dependency which I had to install. Any help would be immensely appreciate as I have been struggling with this issue for quite a while and haven't found very much coverage, if any, on it elsewhere.

```
BOOL success = DeviceIoControl(hDevice, 
      IOCTL_PRIORITY_BOOSTER_SET_PRIORITY,
      &data,
      sizeof(data),
      nullptr, 
      0,
      &returned,
      nullptr);
```

Happy to add more information as requested.

Comment: There is a backslash in your CTL_CODE - `\0x800`. Remove it.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe the issue was as simple as that. I feel incredibly stupid now, thank you for the help! I really appreciate it.